# Submitting multiple research proposal to the same RFA as PI and CoPI

Tags: ethics, funding, conflict-of-interest, research-proposal

There are many benefits of being a PI while submitting a proposal to funding agencies, including that you often manage the funding and you get credits for tenure-track among others. Recently, I was invited to submit a proposal as a Co-PI to a specific RFA call by some colleagues. I accepted to be part of the proposal, however, I have been thinking about submitting another proposal as PI to the same RFA call. Would this be considered unethical, uncollaborative by the other PIs or reviewers? Obviously, the research would be different but I will still focus on my expertise.

Comment: This might depend on how competitive the awards are, and how many of them might be available, both in general and to an individual institution.